# Display post from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, loop

I have this Custom Post Type (CPT) defined at `functions.php`:

```
register_post_type(
    'opinion',
    array(
        'label'              => __( 'Opiniones' ),
        'singular_label'     => __( 'Opinión' ),
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'menu_position'      => 2,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'opinion', 'with_front' => true ),
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'author' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'opiniones',
        'capabilities'       => array(
            'publish_posts'       => 'publish_opiniones',
            'edit_posts'          => 'edit_opiniones',
            'edit_others_posts'   => 'edit_others_opiniones',
            'delete_posts'        => 'delete_opiniones',
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_opiniones',
            'read_private_posts'  => 'read_private_opiniones',
            'edit_post'           => 'edit_opinion',
            'delete_post'         => 'delete_opinion',
            'read_post'           => 'read_opinion',
        )
    )
);
```

And have this code at `front-page.php`:

```
<?php
$prev_post_ids = array();
$prepost       = $post;
$normal_args   = array(
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'order'               => 'desc',
    'meta_query'          => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_custom_blog_enhome',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'      => 6
);

$normal_query  = new WP_Query( $normal_args );

if ($normal_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($normal_query->have_posts()) {
        $normal_query->the_post();
        $prev_post_ids[] = $post->ID; ?>
        <?php $field = 'custom_blog_exclusivo';
        if ( ! ($$field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_'.$field, true ))) {
            $$field = "";
        } ?>

        // here goes the HTML markup for display the post not relevant here

    <?php }
}
$post = $prepost;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

But CPT from `slug=opinion` aren't show. What I need to change in order to display them on `front-page.php`?

**Performing tests**

I'm doing some test and my code now looks as follow:

```
$prev_post_ids = array();
$prepost       = $post;
$normal_args   = array(
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'order'               => 'desc',
    'meta_query'          => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_custom_blog_enhome',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'      => 6,
    'post_type'           => array('opinion','especiales','clasificados','portadadeldia','anunciantes','post','pages')
);

$normal_query  = new WP_Query( $normal_args )
```

But still not showing posts from `opinion`, why? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
'post_type' => array('post', 'opinion')
```

to your `$normal_args` array and maybe remove the `meta_query`?. Are you sure you have any `opinions` with a `_custom_blog_enhome` of `1`?

Start from

```
$normal_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'opinions',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
```

and add arguments one by one and watch the results.

Comment: Did you see the test I made? There is those values or you mean the order of them?

Comment: What are you getting if you only set post type and status? Do you have any posts in `opinion` CPT?

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of them, also added a new one just to see if I get it but no luck

Comment: It should work. To make sure no `opinions` are returned, you should dump `$normal_query` before your loop. If there are no `opinions`, there must be some filter on `pre_get_posts` that overrides the `post_type` on the fly somewhere else in your code (or in some plugin you have installed).

Comment: This is the query performing by Wordpress `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'opinion', 'especiales', 'clasificados', 'portadadeldia', 'anunciantes') AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND (( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_custom_blog_enhome' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '1')
) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 6` but the post from `opinion` are not there, why?

Comment: Most likely it's the `AND (( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_custom_blog_enhome' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '1') )` part. If you have published opinions they should show up in the results. Run the query on the db in `adminer` without the meta_key part and you will most likely see that i'm right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20821/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-reynierpm).

Comment: Nevermind I fix the issue by adding an `OR` instead the `AND` so thanks